# Different Color to Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

How can I give different colors to the x-axis labels of Google Visualization like 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007 in the first figure of below link?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.

I have used this code.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: You cannot change the color of individual labels, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
options = [{ 
   //you can set the baseline color of the axis and the text like :
   hAxis: {
       baselineColor: '#c9311b',
       textStyle:{color: 'red'}
   },
   vAxis: {
       baselineColor: '#cccccc',
       textStyle:{color: 'yellow'}
   },
   // and the series (labels) like : 
   series=[{targetAxisIndex:0, 
       color:'red'}, 
       {targetAxisIndex:1,
       color:'blue'
    }]
}]
```

where the targetAxisIndex the dimension is

Comment: It is changing colors of legends like(sales & expences) not color of haxis label(2005, 2006 etc).

Comment: I want different color on xaxis label. It is giving same color. Example putting this textStyle:{color: 'red'} converts all hAxis label to red.